# Google Sheets sorting and lookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a table like this :

[image]

Now I would like to perform a column lookup on this where I give the Client(B) and get return value from Status(C) but the latest date from Date (A).

I tried using vlookup but I am not getting the right return value.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to sort the data in descending order by date, and then do a lookup through your search keys, which in this case would probably be the list of unique values in `B2:B`.

You can do that by inserting this array formula in the top left cell of a free two-column range:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    unique(B2:B); 
    iferror( 
      vlookup( 
        unique(B2:B), 
        sort(B2:C, A2:A, false), 
        columns(B2:C), 
        false 
      ) 
    ) 
  } 
)
```